# logstash: Error, cannot retrieve cgroups information

Tags: logstash

I'm trying to run logstash using specific config file:

```
$ /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --debug -f $HOME/conf.d/conf2.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
[2018-06-26T15:00:41,046][DEBUG][logstash.pipeline        ] Pushing flush onto pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6556cab@/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:247 sleep>"}
[2018-06-26T15:00:45,417][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ParNew"}
[2018-06-26T15:00:45,418][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] collector name {:name=>"ConcurrentMarkSweep"}
[2018-06-26T15:00:45,419][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] Error, cannot retrieve cgroups information {:exception=>"NoMethodError", :message=>"undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass"}
```

have you any idea about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message appears then MySQL is unreachable

Comment: Please explain how you solved it, I am using a simple config to read/write to text files and there is no output. Debugging gave me the same cgroups error.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem, you're probably running on an old version of Logstash.
Please, refer to these GitHub issue https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/6797

I had this problem in Kubernetes with version `6.2.4`, but it works with `7.10.1`