# Logstash No output - Error, cannot retrieve cgroups information {:exception=>"NoMethodError"

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack

I am trying to simply copy data from input to output file using logstash but getting no data in output.

This is my config

```
input {
        file {
                path => "/root/input.log"
                start_position => "beginning"
                sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
                ignore_older => 0
 }
        }
output {
        file {
                path => "/root/output.log"
            }
        }
```

Command I am using to run logstash :

`bin/logstash --path.settings=/etc/logstash -f logstash.conf --debug`

Error I am getting ( after using --debug )

`[logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.cgroup] Error, cannot retrieve cgroups information {:exception=>"NoMethodError", :message=>"undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass"}`

I guess this is only causing no output to occur in the output.log. Any fixes ?

Related Question ( but didnt help me ) : [logstash: Error, cannot retrieve cgroups information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077871/logstash-error-cannot-retrieve-cgroups-information)

Comment: Remove `=` sign between `--path.settings` and `/etc/...`.

Comment: @Michael Dz didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The issue was that the input file was not accessible ( permission issues )

Although the same error is still coming, but logstash is giving output as expected.